# Jenkins Post build deploy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins CI in my project, I am able to successfully build the project and I have no issues in deploying it in the container after every successful build. Now I have a condition that the deployment to the container has to happen only if there is a change in the release properties file. If there is no change in the release properties file then the project has to be built but no deployment should happen.

Since I am new to Jenkins I am trying out all the options, I am sure that someone must have been in the similar situation, please share your thoughts or ideas. Incase if I find something I will post it.

Highly Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Is your release properties file in a repository? What is the format?

Comment: yes the release properties file is in repository and it is in key value pair format(build.number=99)..

Comment: You could have two jobs. One would do a build only and be triggered by a commit to the project repo. The second would be triggered by a commit to the release properties file and would check out the latest then build + deploy.

Comment: That's great idea. Is there any way in Jenkins that I can check for a specific file from the project repo whether it is checked in? Do we have any plugin or something like that to verify? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Yes, use the SVN plugin here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin You can set the plugin to watch any level of the repo from base up to a specific file. The plugin will poll the repository at a specified interval and trigger the job if there are changes.

Comment: I think this Plugin by default comes up with the Jenkins installation and it gets the details of the recent file changes that has been checked into SVN, if this what this plugin is all about right now I am at that stage. I wanted to leverage this and check whether the name of the file that I needed is present in the file checked in list and if it is present it should trigger the build and deploy, if not just the build is fine. Thanks for sharing your knowledge CIGuy. – Hakuna Matata

Answer (score 1):

If this is still not answered!!

This can we easily done using Script Trigger plugin.
This allows you to run a shell/batch script and based on the exit code of this script the build will be executed.

You can keep track of the last modified date of the properties file and if it changed then you can go ahead and build, if not there will not be any build until the change happens.

Hope this helps (if at all required now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should install the "**Post-Build Script Plug-in**" in your Jenkins. The previous answer was mentioning a plugin that is no longer available.

Then you can add sub build steps, like executing a shell script

[image: see screenshot]script

You can also publish a Docker container, etc.